# jQuery built-in function name is stripped out in editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-code

Some of my jQuery built-in functions names have been crossed out in VSCode but are still working as expected in the browser.
I don't know how to explain this, but here is a picture.

[image]

and

[image]

The `ready()` and `click()` functions are ruled out.
When I use`$(document).on("click", ".add-expense", function(){});` it works properly.

Should I worry about this?

Answer (score 1):

This has been added to VS Code release August 2020 (version 1.49)

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49#_deprecated-tag-support-for-javascript-and-typescript

> **Deprecated tag support for JavaScript and TypeScript**
>
> VS Code now supports the `@deprecated` JSDoc tag in JavaScript and TypeScript files. To mark an API as deprecated, simply add a `@deprecated` JSDoc comment